# Difference between Fork/Join and Map/Reduce

Tags: mapreduce, fork-join

What is the key difference between Fork/Join and Map/Reduce?

Do they differ in the kind of decomposition and distribution (data vs. computation)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One key difference is that [F-J](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf) seems to be designed to work on a single Java VM, while [M-R](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) is explicitly designed to work on a large cluster of machines. These are very different scenarios.

F-J offers facilities to partition a task into several subtasks, in a recursive-looking fashion; more tiers, possibility of 'inter-fork' communication at this stage, much more traditional programming. Does not extend (at least in the paper) beyond a single machine. Great for taking advantage of your eight-core.

M-R only does one big split, with the mapped splits not talking between each other at all, and then reduces everything together. A single tier, no inter-split communication until reduce, and massively scalable. Great for taking advantage of your share of the cloud.

Comment: More specifically, F-J allows workers to steal subtasks from each others' queues.  This is not possible if the worker threads are on different machines (and thus do not have shared memory.)

Comment: According to the [MapReduce Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), M-R is not necessarily restricted to a single tier of forked tasks.

Comment: what's the difference between fork/join & mapreduce outside the context of Java?

Answer (score 20):

There is a whole scientific paper on the subject, [Comparing Fork/Join and MapReduce](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/cs/techreps/docs/files/HW-MACS-TR-0096.pdf).

The paper compares the performance, scalability and programmability of three parallel paradigms: fork/join, MapReduce, and a hybrid approach.

What they find is basically that Java fork/join has low startup latency and scales well for small inputs (<5MB), but it cannot process larger inputs due to the size restrictions of shared-memory,
single node architectures. On the other hand, MapReduce has significant startup latency (tens of seconds), but scales well for much larger inputs (>100MB) on a compute cluster.

But there is a lot more to read there if you're up for it.